# mapbox marker rotation/bearing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox-gl-js

is there any chance to set the rotation for a marker? For now, I set the map bearing to the angle of one marker, but the others should have their own marker bearing.

At the moment, I'm using the marker definition like so:

```
var marker_el = document.createElement('div');
marker_el .className = 'marker';
var new_marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(marker_el)
    .setPopup(marker_PopUp);
```

and set it to the map:

```
new_marker.setLngLat([lon, lat]);
new_marker.addTo(map);
```

I'm using JS and react and for the map mapbox-gl

Answer (score 3):

so because there are no answers, I self answer my post with a working solution for me:

```
var angle = "yourAngle";
var rotateString = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)";

var marker_el = document.createElement('div');
marker_el.className = 'marker';
var new_marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(marker_el);
new_marker.addTo(map);

/* important here is to append the rotate property because the transform 
property is already being updated */
marker_el.style.transform = marker_el.style.transform + rotateString;
```

Comment: How did you find that out? I've been trying to solve this for a very long time !

Comment: @mwarren https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_transform.asp and for the waiting part: actually I simply debugged it. I checked out the values before the marker was set on the map and after. There I found out that the addTo() method was updating the transformation of the element to the standard values. So i put it after the calls (I had multiple of them).

Comment: Note that recent versions of mapbox-gl (mine is 1.6.1) offer *marker.setRotation()*

Comment: The marker.setRotation() function seems to be the way to go.